# Laravel 5 how to return previous view without including the most recent $_GET parameters

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I have the following method which correctly removes a member from a group and returns the view of the list of group members. But the URL has the $request member_id and group_id appended to it so that repeating to remove another member throws a route error.
The flow is like this: a form allows selecting a group from a list, it posts to
this method, which produces the group list.

```
public function postViewGroup(Request $request)
{
    $group = $this->loadGroup($request); //selects correct group from form data

    return View::make('groups/group_view')->with([
        'group'     => $group, 
        'title'     => 'Group Members',
        'group_name'=> $group->getName()
    ]);
}
```

Each row of the list holds a button:

```
<a href = "detach/{{$member->id}}/{{$group->id}}">Remove<\a>
```

to allow removal of member from list, which routes to this method:

```
public function getDetach($member_id,$group_id)
{
    $group = Group::find($group_id);
    $group->member()->detach($member_id);

    return View::make('group_view')->with([
        'group'     => $group,
        'title'     => 'Group Members',
        'group_name'=> $group->getName()
    ]);
}
```

Now I get back to the list with the member removed but the URL has (e.g.)"/detach/39/4" appended to it which means that repeating the flow for another member produces an error. I want to reload the group view without having to select the group again which is what i get if I

```
Return Redirect::back();
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer.
my button hyperlink has to be:

```
<a href = "../../../detach/{{$member->id}}/{{$group->id}}">Remove<\a>
```

this seems to work perfectly.